# Django: Filtering and Manipulating Objects in Python vs SQL

Tags: python, django, performance, django-queryset

I have a model which looks like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date = models.DateField()
    units = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=4, default=0)
    ...
```

I need to group all of the objects by their date (ie by week, month, etc). For each group, I need to sum the total units and cost and perform a few other miscellaneous operations.

I can do most of that just by hitting the database a bunch. For instance, if `periods` is a list of tuples with begin and end values as `datetime.dates`, I could do:

```
for period in periods:
    mymodels = MyModel.objects.filter(date__gte=period[0], date__lte=period[1])
    sums = mymodels.aggregate(Sum('units'), Sum('cost'))
    # do other stuff
```

Or I could get all the models at once and then do the rest in python, like:

```
models = MyModel.objects.all()
for period in periods:
    period_models = [x for x in models if x.date >= period[0] and x.date <= period]
    period_units = sum(x.units for x in period_models)
    period_cost = sum(x.cost for x in period_models)
    # do other stuff
```

Which of these is the better approach, or is there a 3rd option? I'm worried about speed when I get to something like 50k objects.

With the first approach I'm hitting the database twice for every period (once to get the relevant models, once to sum the values), which seems heavy handed. With the latter approach I'm only hitting the database once, but I'm loading a bunch of stuff into memory (but, on the other hand, memory is cheap).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say let the database handle the processing. It may not make a noticeable difference on smaller sets, but anything of significant size will be handled more efficiently by the database. They will generally do a better job of taking advantage of multiple cores and are heavily optimized for this type of number crunching.

I did a quick search and came up with this article.

http://patshaughnessy.net/2015/6/18/dont-let-your-data-out-of-the-database

Essentially let your database handle as much of the processing as it can and only take your result and do any finish-up you may need. Even though you're hitting it twice, it'll scale better.